# Match two histogram using sliding window technique

Tags: matlab

Here is my code containing two part: one is for input image & another for making a window and displaying all the windows...

How can i match histograms using this code.

```
%% Input image section
[fname path]=uigetfile('*.jpg','select an image');
fname=strcat(path,fname);
image=imread(fname);
image=imresize(image,[42 42]);

%% Display main image
figure;
subplot(4,3,1);
imshow(image);
title('Normal Pic');

%% Making a window & displaying the windows
windowWidth = 40;
windowHeight = 40;
for j = 1:imageHeight - windowHeight +1
for i = 1:imageWidth - windowWidth + 1
    window = image(j:j + windowHeight - 1, i:i + windowWidth - 1, :);
    subplot(4,3,1+(j-1)*3+i);
    imshow(window);
    title('Window');

end

end
```

Comment: What have you tried? This looks like you are asking to write the code for you! I hope that is not whats happening

Comment: What type of Histogram are we talking about? 2D (RGB HSV, ), 1D (Grayscale) and why do you want to compare them with a sliding window? Are you looking at histograms of small regions?

Comment: @cagatayodabasi I want to use hue histogram.I want to make hue histogram for each window and match them with another single histogram which i will obtain from target object.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I want to use hue histogram.I want to make hue histogram for each window and match them with another single histogram which i will obtain from target object.

Comment: What dod you tried to get that? why didnt it work?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I want to detect a object by comparing 2 histograms.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I think he has not tried yet.

Comment: @cagatayodabasi then this question is bad, as we do not write peoples code

Comment: i m new to matlab and these type of things...so i m confused..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already successfully created your window. So, let's say your second image is called `im`.

I'm just sharing a pseudocode.

```
% RGB to HSV conversion
im_hsv = rgb2hsv(im);
image_hsv = rgb2hsv(image);

% Histogram calculation
im_hist = imhist(im_hsv(:,:,1));

% Your double for loop goes here
for for
    % Window is dynamically changing, so we need to calculate the histogram in loop 
    window_hist = imhist(window(:,:,1));

    % Calculate pairwise distance 
    D = pdist(window_hist, im_hist);

    % Your program logic goes here with D 
end
end
```

Take a look at pdist()'s [documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html). You can specify which metric you will use. Also, I like the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html) of OpenCV about the histogram comparsion.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) let me try it.